# AWS WorkSpace - allow only trusted devices with certificate authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I am trying to implement Allow only trusted devices feature on AWS Workspaces with simple AD.

Can someone please guide me how to generate self-signed root & client certificate with following features.

Certificates must be Base64-encoded certificate files in CRT, CERT, or PEM format.
Certificates must include a Common Name.
The maximum length of certificate chain supported is 4.
Amazon WorkSpaces does not currently support device revocation mechanisms, such as certificate revocation lists (CRL) or Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP), for client certificates.
Use a strong encryption algorithm. We recommend SHA256 with RSA, SHA256 with CEDSA, SHA381 with CEDSA, or SHA512 with CEDSA.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: For future readers, check out this blog: https://www.brunton-spall.co.uk/post/2020/04/28/Using-AWS-Workspaces/

Comment: @IchingChang Hi, I follow your blog, but still fail to connect with windows laptop, may I ask how you install certificate on windows laptop finally? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create CA first:

```html
SERVER_NAME=fred
DOMAIN_NAME=domain.local

export $SERVER_NAME $DOMAIN_NAME

openssl genrsa -out CA_$SERVER_NAME.$DOMAIN_NAME.key 2048 

openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key CA_$SERVER_NAME.$DOMAIN_NAME.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out CA_$SERVER_NAME.$DOMAIN_NAME.pem -subj "/C=GB/ST=MyCounty/L=MyTown/O=MyOrganisation/OU=MyOrganisationUnit/CN=$SERVER_NAME.$DOMAIN_NAME
```

Then you can create certificates signed from the CA you just created.

```html
openssl genrsa -out $SERVER_NAME.$DOMAIN_NAME.key 2048

openssl req -new -key $SERVER_NAME.$DOMAIN_NAME.key -out $SERVER_NAME.$DOMAIN_NAME.csr -subj "/C=GB/ST=MyCounty/L=MyTown/O=MyOrganisation/OU=MyOrganisationUnit/CN=$SERVER_NAME.$DOMAIN_NAME.client"

openssl x509 -req -in $SERVER_NAME.$DOMAIN_NAME.csr -CA CA_$SERVER_NAME.$DOMAIN_NAME.pem -CAkey CA_$SERVER_NAME.$DOMAIN_NAME.key -CAcreateserial -out $SERVER_NAME.$DOMAIN_NAME.crt -days 365 -sha256
```

Now you have a CA and a certificate created, you can test that the certificate is created from the CA by running:

```html
openssl verify -CAfile CA_fred.domain.local.pem fred.domain.local.crt
```

Comment: Note for future readers: if the client is MacOS, you will have to convert the cert and private key to .p12, otherwise MacOS will only load the certificate but not the private key.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @IchingChang, article https://www.brunton-spall.co.uk/post/2020/04/28/Using-AWS-Workspaces/ is really helpful.

For future readers, if you still struggling with this problem, also try with bruntonspall's github link: https://github.com/bruntonspall/AWSWorkspacesCA

The following step is create all keys and certificates in same machine (CA machine), for prod use case, you should create client public and private key in client machine:

1. (only do this step if you want to renew or did not create and upload your CA public key before) run `./CA/gen_CA.sh`, which will generate CA's private and public key, copy the public key (.pem file) and upload it onto AWS Workspaces's Directory Service's Access Control Options (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/trusted-devices.html#configure-restriction).
2. run `./client/gen_client.sh`, which will generate client private and public key and corresponding CA sign certificate.
3. copy pfx (or say p12) certificate file to your windows laptop, click install, select current user and personal store.

Now you should be able to login with your workspaces client (suppose you already setup AWS Workspaces side correctly with other settings).